# Как создать for цикл в html файле чтобы счётчик использовал обьекты из Питона?

Tags: php, javascript, html, python

У меня есть код на питоне:

```
from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def data():
    total = {}
    engine=create_engine('mysql://eleonora:eleonora@openstack2-prakt.in.linux.edu.lv/nova', echo=False)
    connect=engine.connect()

    q0 = text(
    "SELECT project_id FROM instance_actions "
    "WHERE user_id LIKE :e0 "
    )
    users = connect.execute(q0, e0='7c1%')
    seen=set()
    newwlist=[]
    for user in users:
        tt=tuple(user)
        if tt not in seen:
            newwlist.append(user)
            seen.add(tt)

    leng=len(newwlist)
    for i in range(0, leng):
        project_id=newwlist[i][0]

        q = text(
        "SELECT instance_uuid FROM instance_actions "
        "WHERE project_id LIKE :e1 "
         )
        instances = connect.execute(q, e1=project_id).fetchall()
        seen=set()
        newlist=[]
        for item in instances:
            t=tuple(item)
            if t not in seen:
                newlist.append(item)
                seen.add(t)

        total[project_id] = {}
        total[project_id] ['inst_id'] = []
        length=len(newlist)
        for i in range(0, length):
            inst_id=newlist[i][0]
            total[project_id]['inst_id'].append(inst_id)
            query = text(
            "SELECT unix_timestamp(created_at), action FROM instance_actions "
            "WHERE instance_uuid LIKE :e2 "
            )
            result = connect.execute(query, e2=inst_id).fetchall()
    return {'total' : total}
```

Функция возвращает объект с данными: project_id, inst_id, выводит как массив в массиве. Как написать в html цикл с счётчиком, который будет проходить через все inst_id? Можно на php и на javascript.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

**Так, давайте разберемся с тем, что такое питон, html, js и php**

Питон — интерпретируемый язык программирования, который выполняется в демоне/консоле/где-то еще. То есть у вас есть интерпретатор (`python.exe`, к примеру), который читает код, парсит его и последовательно выполняет — делает какие-то операции.

html — язык разметки. НЕ язык программирования.
`Следует отметить, что язык разметки неполон по Тьюрингу и обычно не считается языком программирования`. И он не выполняется. Он отображается браузером. Браузер парсит html, на его основе строит [DOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) (объектную модель документа) и ее рисует на страничке.

JS — это язык, который выполняется «в браузере» во время и после загрузки страницы. JS может на лету менять DOM, чем и славен.

PHP — это язык, выполняющийся на сервере, как и питон (в вашем случае). Он, хоть и пишется между html, никакого отношения к нему не имеет. Сервер перед тем, как отправить страницу клиетну, ищет на ней php код и, подобно интерпретатору питона, запускает его. Особенность в том, что php код пишется непосредственно внутри страницы, между html тегами, что смущает новичков: они не особо отличают html, js и php (а еще и css иногда =).

Это было короткое и очень-очень грубое повествование о разнице технологий, упомянутых в вопросе. Там еще куча нюансов и подробностей, я советую в это как-нибудь вникнуть, но самое главное — понять эту разницу. (Может вы ее понимаете, но судя по `Как написать в html цикл с счётчиком, который будет проходить через все inst_id? Можно на php и на javascript` — не похоже.

**Теперь про вопрос**

В html, как видно из текста выше, вы ничего такого не напишете. Теперь нужно понять, а что же именно вам нужно. В принципе, вы можете написать как-то так:

```
print('<ul>')
for i in ...:
    print('<li>%s</li>' % i)
print('</ul>')
```

Получите html код, никаких проблем.

Но это, конечно, не удобно. Во всех web-серверах (которые знаю, по крайней мере) используются html шаблонизаторы (jinja2, к примеру).

Работает так: у вас есть html файл с шаблоном и ваш основной код на питоне.

Python:

```
# некоторые действия
...
# У вас есть библиотека, предоставляющая функцию рендера html
html = render_template_frm_file('/.../template.html',
                                context={'title': 'hello!',
                                         'data': [1, 2, 3]})
```

template.html:

```
<html>
    <header>
        ... (все, что полагается)
    </header>
    ...
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for i in data %}
            <li>{{ i }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</html>
```

В итоге в переменной `html` питона окажется html код такого содержания:

```
<html>
    <header>
        ... (все, что полагается)
    </header>
    ...
    <h1>hello!</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</html>
```

Думаю, понятно, что произошло.

На php это выглядит так же, только можно считать, что шаблонизатор и язык слиты воедино:

```
<ul>
    <?php
        ...
        foreach($array) as $i){
            echo "<li>$i</li>";
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Окей, это все происходило на сервере.

А на клиенте, когда html уже показывается пользователю, работает javascript. Он работает совсем по другому, к примеру:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('hello_word_div').innerHTML = 'Hello!';
</script>
```

Как видите, тут уже наши html теги выступают в роли «операндов»: мы нашли элемент с id `hello_word_div` и поменяли его html. Интерактивненько.

Ну и, в общем-то, надеюсь, дал направление к размышлению и осмыслению (и надеюсь что помог). Теперь стоит вам переформулировать вопрос — на чем же именно вам хочется цикл? На питоне и пыхе пример привел.

Answer (score 1):

Если используешь питон то используй SQLAlchemy ORM для работы с базой данных. Упростит как и жизнь так и сам код.

Далее. В HTML ты никогда не напишешь код, потому что HTML это разметка документа, а не язык программирования.

Еще было бы неплохо показать что возвращает функция data а в частности ключ total.

В общем вот небольшой пример на JS который возможно тебе поможет

```js
var data = [
        {project_id: 1, inst_id: 1},
        {project_id: 1, inst_id: 2},
        {project_id: 1, inst_id: 3}
    ];
    
var total = 0;

data.forEach(function(item) {
    total += item.inst_id;
});

console.log(total); // -> 6
```

Answer (score 1):

*Далее. В HTML ты никогда не напишешь код, потому что HTML это разметка документа, а не язык программирования.*
Ну это же код, страница html выполняется в зависимости от условия в ней:

```
<body>
{% if kdms %} 
            
{% for kdm in kdms %}  
    {% if kdm.name == "МД-651" %}                     
    {% block content %}
        <img src = '{% static "image/20190926_090211.jpg" %}'     width = 31% height = 31%>
        <img src = '{% static "image/фон.jpg" %}'     width = 31% height = 31%>
    {% endblock %}
    {% else  %}
        <p> No photo </p> 
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}  
{% endif %}
</body>
```